# how to catch startActivty deep link error for Android

Tags: android, deep-linking

I'm trying to trigger a deep link like:

```
yelp://
```

which should be `yelp:///` but I want to verify that link fails and tell the user to enter the right address or install the application.  Here is my try block:

```
try{
            startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                    Uri.parse(message)));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e){
            throw new RunTimeException("Please install the application you are trying to trigger." + e.toString());**
}
```

The RunTimeException is not showing.  Any suggestions on how to display a dialog or such to the user for this Exception.  TIA.

Comment: Have you tried using a generic `Exception` instead of an `ActivityNotFoundException` in your catch block to see what is thrown?

Comment: Throwing an exception is not supposed to display a message, it will just make the app crash. Try showing a DialogFragment instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something along these lines

```
public static boolean canLaunchIntent(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
    final PackageManager mgr = ctx.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> list = mgr.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;
}
```

To check with the package manager and determine if there is an activity that can handle the intent you are sending.